# Number of dimensions

Tags: r

Good Afternoon! When I withdraw the obtained data 'pv', R illustrates 118 matriсes :

```
[[1]]
              Estimate    Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.2105808 0.557122939
Rcm[, 1]    -0.1825941 0.248647764
Rcm[, 2]    -0.5519795 0.005074583

[[2]]
              Estimate   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.7394133 0.08712924
Rcm[, 1]    -0.5268179 0.00586987
Rcm[, 2]    -0.4915758 0.03754552
```

But I need only column with P-value for all matrices. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply` to extract the second column as a `list`

```
lapply(pv, function(x) x[,2, drop = FALSE])
```

Suppose, if we want it as a single matrix, then `sapply` can be used

```
sapply(pv, function(x) x[,2, drop = FALSE])
#         [,1]       [,2]
#[1,] 0.557122939 0.08712924
#[2,] 0.248647764 0.00586987
#[3,] 0.005074583 0.03754552
```

#### data

```
pv <- list(structure(c(0.2105808, -0.1825941, -0.5519795, 0.557122939, 
0.248647764, 0.005074583), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
 c("(Intercept)", "Rcm[, 1]", "Rcm[, 2]"), c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)"
))), structure(c(0.7394133, -0.5268179, -0.4915758, 0.08712924, 
 0.00586987, 0.03754552), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("(Intercept)", 
"Rcm[, 1]", "Rcm[, 2]"), c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)"))))
```